# Angular Jest testing `Cannot find name 'By'.`

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-test, angular-jest

I am using Jest.JS with Angular. When I try to test the directive, I get the error:

`Cannot find name 'By'.`

```
src/app/directives/error-highlighter.directive.spec.ts:33:46 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'By'.

    33         inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));
```

What is required to install things with my `node_module` -?

directive.spec file:

```
import { ErrorHighlighterDirective } from './error-highlighter.directive';
import { Directive, ElementRef, SimpleChanges, HostListener, Renderer2, Component, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, FormControl, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

@Component({
    template: `<input errorHighlighter formControlName="Url" type="text">`
})
class TestHighlighterComponent { }



describe('ErrorHighlighterDirective', () => {

    let component: TestHighlighterComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHighlighterComponent>;
    let inputEl: DebugElement;

    const fg: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        'Url': new FormControl('')
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [TestHighlighterComponent, ErrorHighlighterDirective],
            imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
            providers: [
                { provide: NgControl, useValue: fg }
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHighlighterComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'));

    });


    it('should create an instance', () => {
        const directive = new ErrorHighlighterDirective(inputEl, fg, Renderer2);
        expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you share your whole `spec.ts` file?

Comment: @jess - spec file added

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, what I meant was `error-highlighter.directive.spec.ts`.

Comment: @jess - directive spec file added

Comment: I think you forgot the `import {By} from "@angular/platform-browser";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import *By* from angular.platform-browser

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser'
```

You can further read [here](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/By).

Comment: Is it only for By or it need to import all the selectors? where can i find full specs?